# Showing SFTP directory structure with TreeView using WinSCP in C#

Tags: c#, treeview, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to achieve the following,
building a `TreeView` component showing all the directories and subdirectories of an SFTP folder using the WinSCP .NET assembly API.

like this:

```
Home ---->SubFolder
     |
     |---->Another Folder -------> MyFolder1
     |                  | -------> MyFolder2
     |
     |---->MyOtherFolder
```

I'm following this approach, but somehow for the WinSCP `RemoteDirectoryInfo` it doesn't work.

```
private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Clear();
    var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
}

private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
    return directoryNode;
}
```

When I follow this approach using `WinSCP.RemoteDirectoryInfo` instead of `DirectoryInfo`, it's not working because `RemoteDirectoryInfo` doesn't have the same properties and methods as `IO.DirectoryInfo`.

I see that the better way to go might be using `EnumerateDirectories`, which will show all folders and subfolders.

```
var fileInfos =
    sftpSession.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
        "/source", "*",
        WinSCP.EnumerationOptions.AllDirectories |
            WinSCP.EnumerationOptions.EnumerateDirectories);           
foreach (RemoteFileInfo fi in fileInfos)
{
    if (fi.IsDirectory) { 
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(fi.FullName);
    }
}
```

but this results in this:

[image: folder tree]

Where I'm trying to achieve this:

[image: folder tree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [WinSCP `Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory) to obtain list of subdirectories and files and a particular folder (instead of `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories` and `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` from your code).

And use [`RemoteFileInfo.IsDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotefileinfo#isdirectory) to differentiate subfolders and files.

```
private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Clear();
    treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(path));
}

private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(string path)
{
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(RemotePath.GetFileName(path));
    var entries = sftpSession.ListDirectory(path).Files;
    var directories =
        files.Where(_ => _.IsDirectory &&
                    !_.IsParentDirectory && !_.IsThisDirectory);
    foreach (var directory in directories)
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory.FullName));
    foreach (var file in entries.Where(_ => !_.IsDirectory))
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
    return directoryNode;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot that did the trick !!